# Abelian Groups and Isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

I am reading in my book about Cyclic groups and ran into this example that I would like a little more explanation on why or why not each group is isomorphic.

a) $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$

b) $\mathbb{Z}^*_{12}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^*_8$

c) $\mathbb{Z}^*_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$

d) $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

e) $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

f) $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on which are/are not isomorphic? I think it's valuable for a student to develop his/her own intuition about this stuff before cranking out a formal proof.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the general concepts such that to have a group be isomorphic it needs to have a group isomorphism exist where its group homomorphism is bijective.

Comment: @Mike: The reason, I believe, that this thread has been closed is because people would like to know what you have actually *tried*. I think it would be helpful if, for example, you edited your question to give us some of your thoughts on question (a). Do you think they are isomorphic or not? (Hint: $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is cyclic. So every isomorphic group is cyclic (why?)...etc.)

Comment: I don't think 7 downvotes are appropriate and hence I upvoted to compensate.

Comment: **Hint:** if you show what you've tried or what is giving you trouble, the question might get more upvotes (or fewer downvotes). This also helps those answering to focus their efforts.

Comment: I have voted to close. The question does not give any sense of what the questioner has tried, and it does not include the context in which the problem was encountered (what class is it, what book is being used, etc.) Moreover, "I would like a little more explanation" is not a question that has an objective answer. A better (more objective) question would be "For each of these pairs of groups, are they isomorphic?".

Comment: @CarlMummert: Although I agree with the overall sentiment of your comment, I think it is asking a bit much to expect OPs to tell you what class it is from, or what book they are using! Sure, ask the OP if you think it will help, but that isn't a close reason in itself...

Comment: (Although as this question is a month old, I do not think the OP will be back anytime soon...so it is all kinda pointless...)

Comment: @user1729: I do not think it is asking very much for the OP to tell us the context in which they encountered the question. We should expect that for all "standard textbook" questions. Knowing the context can be vital for knowing how to write a useful response. I gave two other, equally important considerations for closing in my comment, as well.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I am not disagreeing with your other reasons. Rather, I am saying that the OP should first be asked where it came from before your point becomes a valid close reason.

Answer (score 6):

Why not draw yourself some group tables? In the case of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ we have $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+& (0,0) & (1,0) & (0,1) & (1,1) \\ \hline
(0,0) & (0,0) & (1,0) & (0,1) & (1,1) & \\
(1,0) & (1,0) & (0,0)& (1,1) & (0,1) & \\
(0,1) & (0,1) & (1,1) & (0,0) & (1,0) & \\
(1,1) & (1,1) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (0,0)& \\
\end{array}

Next, look at the group $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
0 & 0& 1& 2 & 3 & \\
1 & 1& 2& 3 & 0& \\
2 & 2& 3& 0 & 1 & \\
3 & 3& 0& 1 & 2&
\end{array}

Can you see a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ that *preserves the group structure*?

In other cases, you can draw tables, or you can ask yourself simple questions like "*Do they have the same number of elements?*" For example, a finite group can't be isomorphic to an infinite group.

Comment: Notice that $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ has characteristic $2$. That is, for each $x\in\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$, $x+x=0$. Consider $1\in\mathbb{Z}_4$; $1+1=2\ne0$.

Comment: @robjohn That is what I wanted the OP to establish for themselves.

Comment: Yes, but since they hadn't responded, I thought a further hint might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Fly by Night's answer: Consider $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$ and try to define an isomorphism $\varphi$. Assuming $+$ is defined as $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a + c, b + d)$ on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Note that $\mathbb Z$ is generated by $1$ hence is cyclic. Assume $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ was generated by an element $(a,b)$. Then from $n(a,b) = (0,1)$ and $m (a,b) = (1,0)$ you deduce that both $a$ and $b$ must be zero. Since $(0,0)$ is the neutral element in $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, it certainly does not generate it. We have therefore shown that $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ cannot be cyclic.

Since cyclicity is preserved by group isomorphisms, $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$ cannot be isomorphic.